# Angular2 routing, how to avoid errors while data is loading

Tags: ajax, routes, angular, lazy-loading

I have a route:

```
@RouteConfig ([
    {path: '/dn/', name: 'Details', component: DetailsComponent}
])
```

DetailsComponent loads data in the ngOnInit method.

Data is shown in the components template with constructs like

```
{{data.prop1.prop2}}
```

But as long as the data is not loaded, I get errors because data.prop1.prop2 does not yet exist.

What is the preferred way in angular2 to solve this problem? With

```
<span *ngIf="data">{{data.prop1.prop2}}</span>
```

or with AsyncRoute, or by setting the template dynamically?

Comment: The easiest way would be to use `<span *ngIf="data">{{data.prop1.prop2}}</span>` for objects and `<span *ngIf="data.length"></span>` for arrays.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Elvis operator

```
{{data?.prop1?.prop2}}
```

this way Angular doesn't try to evaluate `prop1` until `data` has a value != `null`.